# How to get a range from array based on criteria using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I have an array with a list of zip codes associated with the county (id) that belongs to that zip code. See the next screenshot.

[image: xcel]

Currently, I'm using TEXTJOIN in the right table to manually select the zip codes from the left table that match the county ID. What set of formulas could I use to do it automatically for the 4th county?

What I would like to achieve is to show in G5 the list of zip codes corresponding to the ID typed in E5.

Expected values: 32026, 32042, 32044, 32058, 32091, 32622

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `G2` array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter) copied down ;

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(A$2:A$22=E2,B$2:B$22,""))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW. It works perfect. Thank you so much. This is the right answer.